# How do I inject a custom component from js in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

Suppose I create a small component that takes an input and sets a label to show it.

*app/components/testComponent/testComponent.xml:*

```
<Label id="someLabel" loaded="onLoad"/>
```

*app/components/testComponent/testComponent.js:*

```
exports.onLoad = args => {
    const obj = args.object;

    const label = obj.getViewById('someLabel');
    label.text = obj.someString || 'no string given';
};
```

Now I can use this component in any of my pages

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
      xmlns:testComponent="components/testComponent">
    <StackLayout>
        <testComponent:testComponent someString="hello {N}"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

This seems to be the official way to do it and it works. But is there a way to inject this component in the page using javascript only?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the Declarative UI (i.e. xml) is actually a building system that parses the xml and generates the JS so you don't have to.

So if you wanted to manually do this you would leave your component code alone and you would change your main screen code to be like this:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onLoad">
    <StackLayout id='sl'>

    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

The first thing you will notice is we gave the Page a loaded event, you have to have somewhere to actually run your code to attach your component to the visual tree.  The second thing we did was add to StackLayout an id; this technically isn't actually needed -- you can navigate the NS tree and find the proper StackLayout; but for simplicity adding a ID makes it a lot easier.

---

So the JS code in your page would be:

```
var builder = require('ui/builder');
var fs = require('file-system');

exports.onLoad = function(args) {
  // Get our current Page that is being loaded
  var page = args.object;

  // Find our StackLayout
  var stackLayout = page.getViewById('sl');

  // Load our JS for the component
  var path = fs.knownFolders.currentApp().path;
  var componentJS = require(path + '/components/testComponent/testComponent.js');

  // Actually have the builder build the Component using the XML & JS.
  var component = builder.load(path + '/components/testComponent/testComponent.xml', componentJS);

  // And add our component to the visual tree
  stackLayout.addChild(component);
};
```

I believe that because you are adding the child in the loaded event that your page loaded event in the child component will be ran, but don't hold me to that one.  If it isn't then you can manually run it a the same time you are adding it...

Answer (score -5):

where filepath is a script - or even a class the callback function can create an instance of.
This is as if its loaded at page load and shows in most developer tool consoles.

```
        var uuid='xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
             var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
             return v.toString(16);
        });
             var url = filepath + "?" + uuid;//prevent caching - does not work with ajax setup
             try {
                    $.getScript(url, "callbackfunctionname('" + filepath + "')");//getScript callback seems broken so use own
             }
             catch (e) {
                    //error handle
             }
```

Comment: This code has nothing to do with NativeScript.  This appears to be Browser based code...

Comment: I suggest when asking for a javascript only solution you learn to recognize javascript as indeed javascript and not the very vague term 'Browser based code'. How can you want a javascript solution that is not actually javascript ? While the answer above looks okay it is not pure javascript and is created on page load not injected

Comment: The request was for how to do load custom components specifically in NativeScript via JavaScript.  

NativeScript is not a browser and as such things like $ (from JQuery) will not work.   In addition, the screen building system in NativeScript does not have a traditional DOM; meaning that even fully valid JavaScript code that is designed for a browser will not work on it.    Does that clarify why I said browser based code?

Comment: Can I suggest revising the question in that case instead of voting down people that cannot mind read

Comment: Sorry, about that -- I lost points when I down vote it also, so it isn't like it is my best interest to down vote your question -- the reason I did is because it is completely wrong for the platform.  Your code is excellent for a browser using JQuery, and I love your UUID trick.   As for mind reading, at the bottom of the question is the NativeScript tag.